# Suppose a set A is infinite and B is countable. Show that A∪B ∼ A.

Tags: analysis

Suppose a set A is infinite and B is countable. Show that A∪B ∼ A.

What I am thinking:

1. Choose S, a countable subset of A.
2. Construct a bijection from S to B.
3. Proof S∪B~S
4. Proof A∪B~S

Question:

What's wrong in the step above? How can I construct such bijection?

Comment: Have you thought using Choice axiom to construct $f: S \rightarrow B$ bijective?

Comment: @user115595: The only use of the axiom of choice here is in the first step. Choosing a countable subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track (except a typo in the last step, you want to show that $A\cup B\sim A$ rather than $S$).

You should prove the more general theorem that the union of two countable sets is a countable set. Then use it to show that there exists a bijection between $S$ and $B\cup S$ (which then extends to a bijection between $A$ and $A\cup B$ in a natural way).

This method, where you prove that something exists, and then just choose such object is very useful when working with arbitrary sets (and you have used it to choose $S$).

(It might be worth noting that the equivalence between "$A$ is infinite" and "$A$ has a countably infinite subset" requires a fragment of the axiom of choice, and cannot be shown constructively in general. So since you can't quite produce an explicit $S$ you can't quite produce an explicit bijection between $S$ and $S\cup B$.

That been said, given $B$ and $S$ in enumerated form (which, again, you can choose such enumerations since they exist), you can construct a bijection between $S$ and $B\cup S$, by following the proof that the union of two countable sets is countable.)